# (ROW_NUMBER) ORDER BY, not indexing correct column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got an query like this:

```
SELECT COL_A, COL_B, row FROM (
    SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Expr1 
                FROM ObjectEventEffect
                WHERE      (ObjectEventId = ObjectEvent.Id) AND (Status = 'E')) AS COLA_A,
                COL_B, 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COL_B ASC) ROW
                FROM         ObjectEvent
) a WHERE a.ROW >= 0 AND a.ROW <= 10
```

Returns:

```
COLA_A  COL_B           ROW
1   2013-10-14 19:51:40.757 4
0   2013-10-16 09:53:46.043 8
0   2013-10-14 19:51:38.443 1
0   2013-10-14 19:51:41.007 5
1   2013-10-16 09:53:46.310 9
0   2013-10-14 19:51:40.053 2
0   2013-10-16 09:53:44.667 6
0   2013-10-16 09:53:46.560 10
0   2013-10-14 19:51:40.413 3
0   2013-10-16 09:53:45.793 7
```

The result I want can be achieved by removing the SELECT of COL_A

```
COL_B                   ROW
2013-10-14 19:51:38.443 1
2013-10-14 19:51:40.053 2
2013-10-14 19:51:40.413 3
2013-10-14 19:51:40.757 4
2013-10-14 19:51:41.007 5
2013-10-16 09:53:44.667 6
2013-10-16 09:53:45.793 7
2013-10-16 09:53:46.043 8
2013-10-16 09:53:46.310 9
2013-10-16 09:53:46.560 10
```

Is there a way to display COL_A and COL_B without breaking the order of COL_B?

Comment: Add an `order by row` ?

Comment: ADD a ORDER BY ROW after the FROM CLAUSE

Comment: Sorry, updated my question with better data now.

Comment: Do you have `OVER(ORDER BY COL_C)` or `OVER(ORDER BY COL_A)` in the query? The result you show does not match with the query.

Comment: Adding an order by in the inner query doesnt work. And adding an order by in the outer query on row will only replace my inner order by.

Comment: Huh? So you are saying when you add `ORDER BY ROW` to the outer query, you don't get the results you want? You're going to need to show more.

Comment: Ran some tests with my code and noticed COUNT() ruins my order by. Sorry for not posting all of my code at the first place. Question is updated.

Comment: Just add `ORDER BY a.ROW` at the end of the query - as everyone has already suggested.

Comment: Yes, that is correct but unfortunately I didn't post my correct query at the beginning which confused me and the answers alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT COL_A,
       COL_B,
       COL_C,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY COL_C) AS [ROW]
FROM A_TABLE
order by [ROW] asc
```

Comment: Ran some tests with my code and noticed COUNT() ruins my order by. Sorry for not posting all of my code at the first place. Question is updated.

Comment: you should be able to do it by using 'order by a.ROW asc' in the end of whole query.